# What happens when a call made to an constructor (clear concept in this context)?

Tags: java, constructor, runtime

I think that java will not initialize the `a` with four values. But I'm wrong, can you please explain me how it does this? I mean what it does when a constructor called because I'm not initialize `a` in constructor.

```
class A  {
    int[] a = {1,2,3,4};
    A() {
        a[0] = 3;
    }
}

class ClassTest1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        A b = new A();

        System.out.println("hey " + b.a[0] );
        System.out.println("hey " + b.a[1] );
    }
}
```

If you explain in detail and with some external resource to understand internals, it could be better for a newbie(me).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9665533/995891 is an interesting and similar case. It's all about the initialisation order of Java

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5

Comment: @zapl thanks, interesting discussion..with "All variables are initialized to their default values, then explicit initializers and anonymous blocks are run in the order they are found in the source file. Finally the constructor is called." http://stackoverflow.com/a/9665723/1579939

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have `int[] a = {1,2,3,4}` it compiles that line into the top of your constructor. So your constructor really looks like this:

```
a = {1,2,3,4};
a[0] = 3;
```

Now, that's a very simplistic definition of what happens. If you had multiple constructors, you could view it as putting it in all of them, but you could also view it as putting it in only one of them (the one you actually called...).

Consider this:

```
class Counter {
    static int nextId = 0;
    static int nextId() { return nextId++; }

    final int id = nextId();
    final String name;

    public Counter() {
        this("Unnamed counter");
    }
    public Counter(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

So you have the option to create a counter without a name, and you get just a default name. Now from the example above, you could extrapolate that your constructors magically turn into the following:

```
public Counter() {
    this.id = nextId();
    this("Unnamed counter");        
}
public Counter(String name) {
    this.id = nextId();
    this.name = name;
}
```

But we know this isn't okay - it attempts to set `id` in the generic constructor, but then goes into the named constructor and tries to set it again. You can't set a final variable once it's been set!

So instead, we can think of it like this: whatever constructor we actually called gets the extra initialization lines, but the ones that might get chained don't get the extra lines.

Comment: So every overridden constructor will have `a={1,2,3,4}`.

Comment: Yes, they will. But it should only get called once. So if you chain constructors, say `public A() { this(null); a[0] = 3; } public A(Object o) { System.out.println("lol"); }` it should only assign it once (which matters if you have something like `int id = IdFactory.next();`!

Comment: Do you mean if I initialize two objects `A x = new A()` and `A y = new A(ObjRf)`. `a` is initialized only for first object.

Comment: Now if you create two distinct objects, it's initialized in both. What you won't get is an initialization for each chained constructor call. I'll edit to make this more clear.